# HttpWebResponse: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, json, github-api

I am trying to post code my gist account. It works if I write a single line of code. But if I write multiline code, I get the error.

For example for running **[1]**:

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

For example for not working **[2]**:

```
python main.py

>>> Programming Quotes

UNIX was not designed to stop its users from doing stupid things, as that would
also stop them from doing clever things. - Doug Gwyn

python main.py

>>> Programming Quotes

And folks, let's be honest. Sturgeon was an optimist. Way more than 90% of code
is crap. - viro
```

I can't post the code in the second example. I get "**The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**" error.

**Maybe You Need To Know**

textBox1.Text for gist description

richTextBox1.Text for content body --> not working for multiline post datas

**My code below:**

```
String jsonMessage = "{ \"description\": \"" +textBox1.Text + "\",  \"public\": true,"
                   + "\"files\": {   \"file1.cs\": {"
                   + "\"content\":\""+ richTextBox1.Text.ToString() + "\"  } }}";

            String _url = "https://api.github.com/gists";

            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(_url)) as HttpWebRequest;


            String userName = "GITHUB_USERNAME";
            String userPassword = "GITHUB_PASSWORD";
            string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
            authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));

            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);
            req.UserAgent = "Test-Agent";
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());

            //MessageBox.Show(jsonMessage);
            writer.Write(jsonMessage);
            writer.Close();

            string result = null;

            using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) // Error Line
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var jo = JObject.Parse(result);
                //MessageBox.Show(jo["url"].ToString());
                textBox2.Text = "https://gist.github.com/" + jo["id"].ToString();

            }
```

How Can I solve this problem? What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't form your json manually.

Comment: @Eser I don't understand I'm sorry.

Comment: Use something like `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { description = textBox1.Text, content = richTextBox1.Text });` to form your json. Most probably your are getting an invalid json by creating it with string operations....

Comment: I agree with @Eser - I have also had such problems with JSON in the past because of not serializing an object using helper classes. About JsonConvert - I think you need Newtonsoft NuGet package to use it.

Comment: @Eser How do I use public parameter?

I think it should be like this 


String jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { description = textBox1.Text, files = "files1.cs", content = richTextBox1.Text });

Comment: @Ali I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> richTextBox1.Text for content body --> not working for multiline post datas

NewLine charachters should be escaped in json string... Since you form your json with string operations you get an invalid json with multiline content...

You can easily test it [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

A correct way of creating a json string is using the json serializer. Since you already use Json.Net, you can do it like

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                new
                {
                    description = textBox1.Text,
                    content = richTextBox1.Text,
                    @public = true
                }
            );
```

Comment: `String jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { description = textBox1.Text, files = "files1.cs", @public = true, content = richTextBox1.Text });`

I try this code. But not working. I get error:

**The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.**

Comment: @Ali I don't know the API you are using, you should read its documents.. Your new error isn't the same as in your question now....  I think your first problem is solved...

Comment: I'm using [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist) api. New version of my code: [http://paste.ubuntu.com/12531955/](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12531955/)

Comment: @Ali I can't answer your every question untill you get whole project done. This is a new question. One question at a time please... I repeat, your problem in the question is solved....